# using trycatch which returns the context of the error

Tags: r, function, try-catch

Here I have this function: (remove object is the name of the functions that we do nt want to compute)

```
    func <- function(x, remove=NULL) {
  if(class(x)%in%"igraph"){
  doclist <- list("edgelist"=function(x) as.edgelist(x),
                    "adjacencyMatrix"=function(x)as_adjacency_matrix(x),
                    "incidenceMatrix"=function(x) as_incidence_matrix(x, 0.001),
                    "data.frame"=function(x) as_data_frame(x))

  sapply(doclist[setdiff(names(doclist), remove)], function(f) f(n))}
  else stop("The input is not an igraph object")
}
```

How can I use tryCatch in this function? If any functions in the 'doclist' faced an error, the next line of 'doclist' would perfomed. The final result messages warnings which call the name of function that had errors and the context of errors.

Comment: Your questions are impossible to understand. Can you write them more clearly, e.g. in several short sentences/questions, or using more punctuation?

Comment: @user1310503 Sorry for misunderstanding. I tried to improved as better as I could. Hope I could correctly what I meant.

Comment: If any functions in `doclist` fail, you want it to carry on, and then at the end you want it to give warnings that contain those function names and error messages. Is that right?

Comment: @user1310503 exactly and of course the calculated value as a data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that shows basically how you can do this. It does not use `igraph` objects or your functions in `doclist`, so you will have to adapt it to use those yourself.

First, here are two functions that raise errors:

```
g <- function(y) { 
    stop("g failed")
}
h <- function(y) { 
    stop("h failed")
}
```

And here is a cleaned up version of your function, using some different functions in `doclist`:

```
func <- function(x, remove=NULL) {
    if (!is(x, "numeric")) 
        stop("x must be a numeric")

    doclist <- list(
        sum = function(x) sum(x),
        g = function(x) g(x),
        makeMatrix = function(x) matrix(x, nrow=3, ncol=3),
        h = function(x) h(x)
    )
    doclist <- doclist[setdiff(names(doclist), remove)]

    warningsText <- ""
    result <- lapply(names(doclist), 
        function(functionName, x) {
            f <- doclist[[functionName]]
            tryCatch(f(x), 
                error = function(e) {
                    warningsText <<- paste0(warningsText, 
                        "\nError in ", functionName, ":\n", e$message)
                    return(NULL)
                }) 
        }, x)

    if (nchar(warningsText) > 0) 
        warning(warningsText)
    return(result)
}
```

And here is what it produces:

```
> func(1:2)
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    1
[2,]    2    1    2
[3,]    1    2    1

[[4]]
NULL

Warning messages:
1: In matrix(x, nrow = 3, ncol = 3) :
  data length [2] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [3]
2: In func(1:2) : 
Error in g:
g failed
Error in h:
h failed
```

Notes:

- For functions that raise errors, this puts NULL in the result list.
- All the errors get put into one warning. In the example with `func(1:2)` this is the second warning shown.
- A `for` loop would be better than `lapply` or `sapply`, but I haven't done that.
- `lapply` is better than `sapply`, as the functions all return different kinds of objects.
- It is best to include `x` in the arguments of the nameless function inside `lapply` and it as a third argument to `lapply`.
- The first argument to `lapply` should be the function names, so that both the function names and the functions themselves are available to the nameless function inside `lapply`.

Comment: Really appreciate for your great nice answer. Thank you for your time. @user1310503

Comment: Thank you for your help on this function, but I had an extra question and I would be pleasant if you answer it: Do you have any idea how to paste the function name in the result instead of [[1]] for example?

Comment: To make the `result` list use the names of the functions, you could just do `names(result) <- names(doclist)` just before the `return`.

Comment: @user1210503 Thank you for your attention and response